# Expand Series of lists into a DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm learning data science and a beginner.
I am struggling with the below Pandas problem for some time now .
Below is the problem description . Please help.

I have the following column of lists in my Data Frame

```
      Time
0     [34, 50]    
1     []          
2     [4, 3, 7] 
3     [13]      
4     [10, 12]
```

I need to expand this series of lists and create a new DataFrame, and I need each first value in its own column, each second value in its own column, and so on. If there isn't an Nth value, the value should be NaN.

Output should be a new DataFrame as below :

```
      t1     t2    t3
0     34     50    nan
1     nan    nan   nan
2     4      3     7  
3     13     nan   nan
4     10     12    nan
```

Thanks,

Comment: max size of a list is 3 which is just `pd.DataFrame(df['Time'].tolist()).add_prefix('t')` why do you have the 4th col?

Comment: My Mistake . I have edited the correct expected output .

Comment: check my comment above, it should solve

Comment: Wow . Its worked . Thanks a lot for your help !!!